# Where to define styles in Parent or child

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS, and I often get confused about where I should define styles, i.e., in the parent or the child element. Please have a look at the code below

```css
.div{
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*font-size: 2rem;*/
  /*if I do this the result is the same*/
}

.ul{
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
    <ul class="ul">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to make sure my code is as good as could be, without any errors and proper readability in the long run that is why I am asking this question.

Is there any defined convention?

What approach is the best in such cases?

EDIT: Making the code and my question clearer.

Comment: what you actually try to achieve ?what you meant by **defined convention**?

Comment: by defined convention, I meant a way of writing styles like in the above example if I define font size In ```div``` or in ```ul``` both gives the same result, I wanted to know what is the best way to write code in such cases or is there any convention about the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's good to define the **font-size** in the parent element ,so you can reduce the code lines and hence your code will run faster. Use the the styles on parent element when ever possible, and add the styles on child element on necessary conditions(if child elements property/style is different from  parent element. for better readability you can use comments. hopes this will helps You.

```css
div{
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  /*if I do this the result is the same*/
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you style your entire application. If you want the same font throughout all the code, then adding the styling to a parent div will do just that.

This will apply this font-size to every div you add in the future

```
div{
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

where the code below will only target unordered lists

```
ul{
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```